# What exactly is the Tensor Property? And how can i check if something is a Tensor?

Tags: tensors

Dear StackExchange users,

i have heard that there is something like a Tensor Property, but what exactly is that and how can i check if something is a Tensor or not?

For example my book on fluid mechanics is talking about the deformation tensor but they also say that the permutation symbol (aka Levi-Civita Symbol) is also a tensor. But i also heared that the Levi-Civita Symbol is just a pseudotensor. So how can i show that the Levi-Civita is not a tensor or a peudotensor? Or to be more general, how can i check this in general? A reference to a very detailed calculation would be nice :).

Thank you for reading my question :).

Comment: for you to gain acquaintance: tensors are multilinear maps and other examples of that are: *the determinant, an inner product, a linear transformation, curvature,...*

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. But I don't see a direct connection of your comment to the question. Could you try to give more details?

Comment: your problem is a blurring state of knowledge, which is going to heal eventually as you work on detailed study. Nowadays tensors are defined as *multilinear transformations*, and, there are a lot of interpretations on the world of applications.